# Shipping flat rate diffrent for each product along with the countries

Tags: magento

I want to change shipping flat rate for  Canada to $10 for product-A and $15 for Product-B and for rest of product it will show the default flat rate for other countries..

Is their any extension available,please help me

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use table rates if you want to use different rule based on country..

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-table-rate-shipping.